# How to show XML language mode in Visual Studio Code

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code, can anyone advise how can I enable XML as language in Visual Studio Code editor? I have been watching couple videos tutorial and I can see all of them has 'XML' available whenever they are editing *.xml file. Mine only has XSL.
Here is mine for example.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPLJW.png)

I have been trying to follow [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file) but honestly I am lost. Here is example I expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJybh.png)

Any guided step will be helpful.

Cheers,
Vian.

Answer (score 2):

you can just [install the visual studio code extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/get-started/extensions) by searching [XML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) plugin it will allow you to edit the xml file